# HTACCESS to NGINX

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to convert htaccess rules to nginx. I'm new to nginx and the online converter doesn't help either.

in www folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

inside public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

could someone help me to convert these htaccess rules to nginx?

Comment: Sure. What have you tried so far, and what doesn't work as expected? Could you add the corresponding line in your nginx configuration so that we can see where you're at?

Comment: I'm completely new to nginx but I tried to convert using [link](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Then please add the results to your post, and explain what you expect. To me, the generated results look good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your config could look like this:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off; 

  location / {
        root /var/www;
  }

  location /public {
        root /var/www/public; # or so, put here your path to public dir
  }

  location @public {
    proxy_read_timeout 180;
    proxy_connect_timeout 180; 
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://host/public;
  }
}
```

I've forgotten some details but maybe you need something similar

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. How does this implement the URL redirection given by the OP in Apache syntax?

Comment: I thought it will help with the redirection, but you're right Naveen is not likely to use mod_proxy.. No idea for the htaccess